# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() возвращает недействительный токен (параметр “kid” не из списка публичных ключей и параметр “exp” это Sun 18 January 1970)

Tags: android, gwt, oauth, google-oauth2

Андроид приложение использует функцию `getToken(Context context, Account account, String scope)` с [GoogleAuthUtil](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil). Бэкэнд сервер фиксирует много случаев, когда токен не действительный. В частности:

1. Токен подписан ключом `kid` который отсутствует в списке ключей
   Google одного из `www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs`,
   `www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/cert`s,
   `www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs`
2. Параметр `exp` это всегда дата 18 Января 1970 г.

Это происходит с реальными пользователями, на реальных устройствах с корректной датой.

Кто-нибудь знает, что может быть не так и как такой может быть, что `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` иногда возвращает недействительный токен?

Comment: Смотрели этот вопрос?: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428603/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-oauth2

Comment: Ну по автору так и не скажешь, да и по домену он тоже не на En.SO, и на русском написан... А Вы так за 2 года и не решили этот и решились на создание нового аккаунта с возобновлением вопроса?

Comment: @V.March Прошу прощения, то не мой, сейчас его изучу. Вот мой: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45616566/googleauthutil-gettoken-returns-invalid-token-kid-is-not-found-in-the-list

Comment: @V.March Просмотрел, спасибо. То общая информация о принципе работы, всё понятно. У меня специфический случай, когда GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() по непонятным причинам возвращает недействительный токен.