# Авторизация с помощью приложения

Tags: php, ооп, auth

Всем привет. Могли бы подсказать где копать?
Есть приложение, созданное и есть Доска объявлений (это мои приложения).
Так вот, мне нужно чтобы при регистрации на этой доске объявлений был значок моего приложения (рядом с обычной формой регистрации - ну это можно сверстать) и чтобы когда посетитель нажимает на него он мог Авторизоваться на этой доске через мое приложение (если он в этом приложении уже зарегистрирован).
К примеру можно авторизоваться через vk, facebook и т.д., наподобие этого.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Принцип работы Oauth2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428603/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%bf-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-oauth2)